# will jquery mobile interfere with the order of script processing in phonegap?

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova, jquery-mobile

good evening to everybody i am having trouble using jquery mobile with phonegap when it comes to firing the deviceready event which contains the code in accessing the device uuid and to know if the device is connected to the internet.

to make my point clearer here is the code that i ran without jquery

omitted code:

```
<body onload="init()">
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">

            var online = false;
            var devceid;

            function init(){
                document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
            }


            function onDeviceReady()
            {
                devceid = device.uuid;
                alert(devceid);
                if (navigator.network.connection.type != Connection.NONE) {
                    alert('device is online');
                    online = true;
                 }else{
                    alert('device is offline');
                 }     
            }
        </script>
```

the code above works perfectly if i don't include the jquery and the jquery mobile scripts.

now here is the code that jquery and jquery mobile is included

```
 <body onload="init()">
    </body>

<script type="text/javascript">

            var online = false;
            var devceid;

            function init(){
                document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
            }


            function onDeviceReady()
            {
                devceid = device.uuid;


                alert(devceid);
                if (navigator.network.connection.type != Connection.NONE) {

                    alert('device is online');
                    online = true;
                    //networklistener();
                 }else{
                    alert('device is offline');

                    //networklistener();
                 }  




            }


        </script>
         <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
                $(document).on( "pagecontainershow", function(){
                    ScaleContentToDevice();

                    $(window).on("resize orientationchange", function(){
                        ScaleContentToDevice();
                    })
                });

                function ScaleContentToDevice(){
                    scroll(0, 0);
                    var content = $.mobile.getScreenHeight() - $(".ui-header").outerHeight() -         $(".ui-footer").outerHeight() -      $(".ui-content").outerHeight() + $(".ui-content").height();
                    $(".ui-content").height(content);
                }

        </script>
```

and after i run the app the function init is being by pass and it goes straight to the function scalecontent i am a bit confuse.

is it a good idea to mix jquery mobile with phonegap?

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try removing the onload funtion

```
    <body>
    </body>

    <script type="text/javascript">

            var online = false;
            var devceid;


            document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

            function onDeviceReady()
            {
                devceid = device.uuid;


                alert(devceid);
                if (navigator.network.connection.type != Connection.NONE) {

                    alert('device is online');
                    online = true;
                    //networklistener();
                 }else{
                    alert('device is offline');

                    //networklistener();
                 }  

            }

        </script>
         <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
                $(document).on( "pagecontainershow", function(){
                    ScaleContentToDevice();

                    $(window).on("resize orientationchange", function(){
                        ScaleContentToDevice();
                    })
                });

                function ScaleContentToDevice(){
                    scroll(0, 0);
                    var content = $.mobile.getScreenHeight() - $(".ui-header").outerHeight() -         $(".ui-footer").outerHeight() -      $(".ui-content").outerHeight() + $(".ui-content").height();
                    $(".ui-content").height(content);
                }

    </script>
```